# Insert span-node and continue writing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a problem adding nodes to a editable div.

I want to add highlighted text in a span and after that the cursor should be outside the added span.

Right now the cursor is inside the added span.

I have created a Fiddle to demonstrate it:
http://jsfiddle.net/4N4ZD/633/

Here is some code:

```
function insertNodeAtCaret() {
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.collapse(false);
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = 'TEXT';
            span.style.background = 'yellow';
            range.insertNode(span);

            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(span);
            range.collapse(false);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4N4ZD/638/

The trick is to add a new text-span and use the methode 'setStartAfter' like so:

```
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = 'TEXT';
        span.style.background = 'yellow';
        range.insertNode(span);

        var textNode = document.createTextNode('\u00A0');
        range.setStartAfter(span);
        range.insertNode(textNode);
        range.setStartAfter(textNode);
        range.collapse(true);

        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
```